# Editing prompts in Equation Engine

Tags: peoplesoft

I Have this equation engine that when you use in one run control page and fill out the edit prompts, it does pull a result but when you use it on another run control page it does not pull anything.

I don't get it, same Equation Engine and same values provided in the prompts but the other run control page does not provide a results when you click the 'Preview Selection Results'.

I have screenshot below for your reference. Please help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the security.

[Equation Engine Security](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56917_01/cs9pbr4/eng/cs/lsfn/task_EquationEngineSecurity-027ec5.html#topofpage).